# intergrate function readline from node.js module into read_line function to get user input

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
//normal nodejs module readline
const readline = require('readline');
//I want to integrate readline module into my function read_line so as to I can get user input by use read_line ,but my mind  is wrong.
//I know the reason is that js function will not be blocked by Function,but I am not familiar with nodejs,how can it block subsequent code run?
function read_line() {
    var input;
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.on('line', function (input) {
        this.input = input;
        rl.close();
    });
    return input;
}

//it will run right now,return undefined
var s = read_line();
//i want to console the user input
console.log(s);
```

I want to integrate readline module into my function read_line so as to I can get user input by use read_line ,I　need help!

Answer (score 1):

readline is ***asynchronous*** function

```
rl.on('line', function (input) {
    this.input = input;
    rl.close();
});
```

The function will wait for the '**line**' event to be triggered

When you call the function **read_line()** will run ***synchronous*** and return input;

You can use a callback function, so when the '**line**' event will be triggered callback function will be called with the value

```
const readline = require('readline');

function read_line(cb) {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.on('line', function (input) {
        cb(input)
        rl.close();
    });
}

read_line(function(input){
    console.log(input);
});
```